# Mysteriously got into caps lock mode after mapping it to control

Tags: keyboard, capslock

Under 18.04 I changed my caps lock key to be another control. I think I did this with a Gnome Shell add-on (just before Firefox performed an upgrade and disabled it.)

Anyway, just a little while ago I found myself in caps lock mode, and I couldn't figure out for the life of me how it happened.

If I've remapped caps lock to control is there another way that caps lock can get enabled?

It took me a while to get back out of caps lock mode. First I had to figure out that shifting in caps lock mode produces lower case letters. Then I stumbled across gnome-tweaks. Then I used gnome-tweaks to interchange caps lock and ESC, and then I used ESC to get out of caps lock mode. And then I used gnome-tweaks to make caps lock another control. It didn't seem like you could use gnome-tweaks to restore normal caps lock behavior -- or at least the options are confusing. There is "Disabled" and "Caps Lock is Disabled" which sound like they do the same thing. I would have expected to see a "Caps Lock is Caps Lock" option or something like that.

But the most pressing questions is: Is there another key combination to enable caps lock?

Comment: quick comment.. `Caps lock Behaviour is Disabled`..  that means Caps Lock is Caps Lock..

Comment: by default its Disabled... meaning Caps Lock is Caps Lock.. if you remapped in any other way.. that is effecting the problems..

Comment: what is the output of the command `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`